# unexpected start tag (body) html

Tags: php, html, header, tags, body-parser

Hi I'm getting this error of unexpected start tag (body) when i run my entire project code. It's showing error on body line

```
?>
 <html>
 <body>
        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $client->getRequestUri();?> ">
        <input type='submit' name='start' value='Start'/>
        </form>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

In this case, the output of your code would be a good start!

Comment: You start your file with closing the PHP tag. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  tags, unless you are going to echo out the  and all other tags too

```
 <html>
 <body>
        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $client->getRequestUri();?> ">
        <input type='submit' name='start' value='Start'/>
        </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

OR

```
<?php
echo "<html>
 <body>
        <form method='GET' action=".$client->getRequestUri().">
        <input type='submit' name='start' value='Start'/>
        </form>
 </body>
 </html>";
 ?>
```

Comment: `" . $client->getRequestUri(); . "`